# CSS display e visibility - Efeitos no SEO

Tags: css, seo

Estou fazendo um website e aplicando algumas técnicas de SEO, porém tenho uma div que necessita ficar oculta (propriedade `display:none;` e `visibility:hidden;`). Qual é o efeito nos mecanismos de busca para este elemento DIV? Funcionaria da mesma forma nas tags `<ul>` e `<ol>`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso causará um impacto ruim no SEO se esta tag em questão for uma tag que você deseja usar para propósitos de entregar conteúdo para os buscadores (pode ser confundido com cloacking).

O ideal é você não esconder tags que contém conteúdo que possa ser usada como palavra-chave no buscador, as tags h1 por exemplo costumam ser péssimas opções para se esconder.

Dê uma olhada no conteúdo dessas tags e pondere se vale apena alterar sua visibilidade nos motores de busca.

Teve uma discussão parecida aqui:
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/54892/can-i-hide-h1-tag-will-it-hurt-seo